# How could I add and image to a JLabel, when the image is in a parent directory in Java?

Tags: java, swing, directory, javac, imageicon

**Using java**

Lets pretend we are in folder "src". The parent directory contains folders "src", "assets" and "bin".
Since I am in the folder "src", how could I get an image from "assets" folder, when it is a parent directory? I would then like to put this image into an ImageIcon and add it to a JLabel, etc.

A source code example is all that is needed, I can work from there.

Comment: The "working directory" may be different then the "installed directory", this makes referencing parent folders like this trouble some and error prone. Better to embedded the images within the application context so that they more easily available at runtime

Comment: @MadProgrammer Okay. I decompiled a verison of Minecraft Infdev, and found their was a asset folder, that had the sprite sheet and a few other icons in it. I was going to use the src from the decompiled .jar file, but Java resets all class names and variable names, so it is incredibly hard to figure out what anything does.